# how to translate a linq expression into sql string use c# code

Tags: c#, sql, linq

how to translate a linq expression for example

```
var query = (from article in ArticleRepository.GetAll()
            join read in ArticleReadRepository.GetAll() on read.ArticleId equals article.Id
            where article.Id>10
            select new 
            {
                article.Title,
                read.ReadCount
            }).ToList();
```

into sql string

```
select article.Title,
       read.ReadCount 
       from ArticleTable as article 
       join ArticleReadTable as read on read.ArticleId = article.Id 
       where article.Id>10
```

use c# code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print `query.ToString()` and you will see the query formed by the LINQ expression

For example,

```
var query = from emp in v.Employees
            select emp;
var sqlQuery = query.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(sqlQuery);
```

The result will be:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: actually,i want to know the implementing of query.ToString()...ok,i will see the source code for it.

Comment: You can retrieve it as a string from `query.ToString` and fire it as a sql query.

Comment: @ReimuLyu Please mark it as an answer if it solved your problem